# C++ "?>" operator

Tags: c++

Could someone explain me what this kind of operator

```
this?>
```

does in C++?

Below example of code with usage of it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    int x;
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    B() {x=1;}
    B(int x) {this?>x = x;}
};

int main()
{
  B c1;
  B c2(10);
  cout << c1.x;
  cout << c2.x;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking a question before even trying to compile code? If you did, you'd notice that there's a syntax error in there. That's because `?>` is not a valid operator (it's probably a typo of `->`).

Comment: Looks like it should be the member access operator `->`, which lets you access member fields and methods through a pointer (`this` is a pointer).

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look a the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and make sure you provide a [verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Seems to me it's a special [syntax error inducing](http://ideone.com/om3rog) operator. How interesting. I've heard only whispers of such things existing.

Comment: Are you using some weird foreigner's keyboard? Is the question mark on the same key as the hyphen?

Answer (score 4):

I think you try to say that `->` becouse `?>` it does not exist.

In the contex, im sure that you want `->`.

You probably have a mistake when you´re typing.
 PD: try to compile before ask

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. You might want to refer to `->`. 
`this` operator is used to access the property of the object calling that function of that class in which the functions is defined, and `->` operator is used to access the properties of that object.